# The Selenium Firefox WebDriver does not start the installed extension

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, firefox-addon, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have:

1. Selenium Firefox WebDriver v.3.8.1
2. Browser Firefox 43
3. XPI-file with firefox add-on

I ran the extension in the browser in two ways: jpm and using the program on the java through selenium firefox web-driver.

In the first case, I run command `jpm run`, which creates a new profile with the extension installed and running. It is important that the extension is automatically launched immediately after opening the browser.

I need to achieve the same result, but with the help of the selenium webdriver. As a result of my program, a profile is created with the extension installed, but the extension does not start the same way as when executing the `jpm run` command.

Help, please, understand what can be the problem.

My code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class MyClass  extends Thread {
    private String baseUrl;
    public MyClass(String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    public void run() {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.addExtension(new File("C:\\switcher.xpi"));
        profile.setPreference("extensions.@switcher.sdk.load.command", "run");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(caps);
        driver.get(this.baseUrl);
    }

    public static void main( String[] args){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette",
            "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        Thread t1 = new MyClass("http://google.com");
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

P.S. I tried to install the firebug with the help of a selenium webdriver - the problem is the same.

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov No, there are no errors. The browser starts with the extension installed, java errors and warnings do not issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. Desired capabilities are deprecated. The way to go is FirefoxOptions.

```
private void initializeFirefoxDriver() {
        //set the location to your gecho driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", USER_DIRECTORY.concat("\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe"));
        //instantiate the Firefox profile
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        //Adding the location to the extension you would like to use
        profile.addExtension(new File("Path_T0_Your_Saved_Extention\\try_xpath-1.3.4-an+fx.xpi"));
        //Setting the preference in which firefox will launch with.
        profile.setPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
        //instantiating firefox options.
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        //Passing the profile into the options object because nothing can ever be easy.
        options.setProfile(profile);
        //passing the options into the Firefox driver.
        webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, GLOBAL_TIMEOUT);
    }
```

The code is not complete and just a snippet, but that will start an extension of your choice. Firebug is no more as well so maybe look at TruePath and Find Path extensions. H

Hope this helped.